# Paint rave TRaveCode128BarCode component direct to Canvas

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I need a barcode image. Without reporting, printing, etc. I would like to use `TRaveCode128BarCode` component.

What is the easiest way?

Is it possible something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  rvc:TRaveCode128BarCode;
begin
  rvc:=TRaveCode128BarCode.Create(nil);
  rvc.Text :='123' ;

  rvc.Paint(self.Image1.Canvas );
end;
```

Comment: Well, what happens when you try it?

Comment: Function in RvClass

function TRaveControl.XI2D(Value: TRaveUnits): longint;
begin { XI2D }
=>  Result := CurrentDesigner.XI2D(Value);
end;  { XI2D }

Run err:


raised exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access violation at address 005173BA in module...

Comment: That code is supposed to be executing in the report designer (as evidenced by `CurrentDesigner`), and not in your application code. Your best chance of getting an answer to this question is to post it to the Rave support forums, where people familiar with the product and its source will see it.

Comment: Yes, I sent a question to their support (support@nevrona.com) but have not heard back.